# How to authorize serviceaccount with OAuth 2.0 ClientId and without clientsecret value in client_secret.json file

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

When I generated `serviceaccount` credentials, `ClientId` got generated for `serviceaccount`. When I downloaded `client_secret.json` file, There is only `ClientId` value and no `clientsecret` value. If there is no `clientsecret` value how will we authorize our client?

Should we generate `OAuth 2.0 ClientId` again from the Create credentials dropdown in *console.developers.com* and authorize our client using `googleauthorizationflow`, pass generated access token to `GoogleCredential` object for `serviceaccount` and make requests?

**Credential Class :**

```
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = Quickstart.class
            .getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(
            JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader( in ));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow,
            new LocalServerReceiver.Builder()
                       .setHost("localhost").build()).authorize("user");

        GoogleCredential gCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(serviceaccountemail)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("privatekeyfile.p12"))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
            .setServiceAccountUser(useremail)
            .setClientSecrets(clientSecrets)
            .build().setAccessToken(credential.getAccessToken())
            .setRefreshToken(credential.getRefreshToken())
            .setExpirationTimeMilliseconds(
                     credential.getExpirationTimeMilliseconds());

        System.out.println("Credentials saved to " +
            DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between service accounts and Oauth2.  If you are trying to authenticate a user so that you can access the users personal data then you need to go with Oauth2.    If you are trying to access data that you personally own and share it with your users then you will need to use a service account.

The json key files are different as is the code you will need to use them.   If you created a service account by mistake I suggest you delete it and create the Oauth2 credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a domain, where in I have created some users and created some appointments for them. Now, with service account if I want to access their calendar information do I need to write GoogleCredentials for serviceaccount in Quickstart.java in addition to existing code.

Comment: your going to have to give the service account access to there accounts in domains admin some place.

Comment: probably if you downloaded the p12 file and not the json service account file.

Comment: Is there any problem if i use p12?

Comment: Its currently in a state of "for backwards compatibility".  Does that mean at some point google will stop supporting it at some point? Probably Have they announced they will stop supporting? Not yet.

Comment: I am not a Java dev there is an example here using a different api looks close to yours https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java.    Just remember to give your service account permissions in domains admin.

Comment: As your suggested link tells me that only serviceaccount authorization using GoogleCredential alone will get refresh, access tokens and is sufficient to make api calls. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The client library handles all of that for you. Try reading this http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/